# Is there a way to add to a next free space in a two-dimensional array? (Python 3.x)

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a way in Python to add to an array to the next free space available? So if (0,0) has already a value, move on to the (0,1) and add the value there. I got as far as shown below, and I'm stuck now..

```
class Array:

    def __init__(self):
        self.array = [[0 for x in range(5)] for x in range(5)]

    def view(self):
        for x in self.array:
            print(x)

    def input(self):
        item = input("Enter an item: ")
        self.array[0][0] = item

array = Array()

array.input()
array.view()
```

Comment: Could you state the problem in another way? Are you trying to find a way to add values to an array (referred to as list generally in python) only if it is empty?

Comment: The way you put your values in ``(``s makes them look like Tuples. I am a bit confused what you are asking but I think I am close enough to be able to help you with a bit more clarification. What is the desired output?

Comment: So if you output this now with input 5, you would get:
['5', 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

but I want to add some more code, so when it asks for the input again, it adds to the next column, and after that to the next column. After the first row will be full, it will move to second row and start from column one again.

Comment: I took a stab at it in my answer. Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Glad to hear it. You can post your own answer to show your own solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one example. I am simply running the loop 9 times. You should be able to work it into your OOP style code. I am also using [pprint](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pprint.html) module from standard library as I like how it displays nested lists.

```
from pprint import pprint as pp


myList = [[0 for x in range(5)] for x in range(5)]

for i in range(9):
    userInput = int(input("Enter an item: "))
    isFound = False # This flag is used to prevent duplicate entries.

    for rowIndex, row in enumerate(myList):
        for colIndex, column in enumerate(row):
            if column == 0 and not isFound:
                myList[rowIndex][colIndex] = userInput
                isFound = True
                break
    pp(myList)
```

Output after last iteration of the loop: (assuming 5 was always entered):

```
Enter an item: 5
[[5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
 [5, 5, 5, 5, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: It helped a lot! Made a few changes and added additional stuff if you're interested, look below. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
class Array:

    def __init__(self):
        self.myList = [[0 for x in range(5)] for x in range(5)]

    def input(self):
        print("You will be asked to put a value, if you want to stop, press RETURN key.")
        for i in range(25):
            print()
            userInput = input("Enter an item: ")
            isFound = False


            if userInput == '':
                menu()

            for rowIndex, row in enumerate(self.myList):
                for colIndex, column in enumerate(row):
                    if column == 0 and not isFound:
                        self.myList[rowIndex][colIndex] = userInput
                        isFound = True
                        break


            print()
            for x in self.myList:
                print(x)

    def remove(self):
        print("Which box do you want to delete? Type in coordinates.")
        x = int(input("Please enter a column: "))
        x -= 1
        y = int(input("Please enter a row: "))
        y -= 1
        self.myList[x][y] = 0
        print()
        for i in self.myList:
            print(i)
        menu()

    def view(self):
        for i in self.myList:
            print(i)
        menu()



array = Array()

def menu():
    print()
    print()
    print()
    print("****************")
    print("      MENU")
    print("****************")
    print("Please choose:")
    print("1. Add an item to the array")
    print("2. Remove an item from the array")
    print("3. View array")
    print()
    print("0. Quit")
    print("****************")
    option = int(input("Enter (1, 2 or 0): "))
    print()
    if option == 1:
        array.input()
    elif option == 2:
        array.remove()
    elif option == 3:
        array.view()
    elif option == 0:
        quit()
    else:
        print("Error..")


menu()
```